# Unable to use imported jar in Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: java, android, jar, import, gradle

I put my dependencies on gradle file

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
   compile files('libs/jaxrs-ri/*.jar')
   compile files('libs/poi/*.jar')
}
```

but nothing happens at all, what I need to let Android to see those libraries?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the .jar in your lib folder. Then right click it, and select 'Add as Library'

Comment: Forgotten import statement perhaps?

Comment: I would like ide will import on the fly or suggest me the import, as I pass the mouse click on the the red class nothing happens except for 'Cannot resolve the symbol Client'

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing your work folders might solve the issue.

Comment: I've synchronized but nothing changed